# Vue3: How to receive @click event on parent DOM?

Tags: javascript, html, vuejs3

I have following structure in **Vue3** template:

```html
template:
/*html*/
`<div class='element1' @click='onClick'>
    <img :src='image_url' />
    <p>{{desc_text}}</p>
</div>`,
data() {
    return {
        image_url: "path/to/image",
        desc_text: "Some text goes here"
    }
},
methods: {
    onClick(e) {
        console.log(e);
    }
}
```

Depending on where I click, console outputs `e.target` to be either `<img>`, `<p>` or `<div class='element1'>`, and it will have `e.path` set to array of elements, from the element that was topmost under the pointer to the bottom-most, while `currentTarget` is set to `null`.

I am looking for a solution where event handler would be called with `e.target` that points to the element that has @click listener added, in this case, `<div class='element1'>`. Not to point to any of it's children.

I've been looking at **Vue3** documentation on the event bubbles, but so far no modifiers fit my need.

For example `@click.self` will only fire if `e.target` is the element that has the event listener, however, if pointer was above any of it's children, it will not fire.

Right now, I use `pointer-events: none;` styling on all children elements I don't want to have their own pointer event handling, which appears to have [sufficient coverage](https://caniuse.com/pointer). However, I'm surprised if Vue does not have any option on it's own to handle this case, maybe I am missing it?

I've read through [Vue3 Event Modifiers](https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/events.html#event-modifiers) document, but no option listed there does this.

In some cases, I have dozen of sub-elements in an element (eg. a card showing image, title, paragraph etc.), and I'd like entire element to be one big button to click on, with just one `@click` event handler set.

Comment: That is weird, I have some similar thing where I rely on currentTarget which is the element where the handler was attached to as opposed to target which is the actual element that was clicked: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/currentTarget

Comment: Did you try combining modifiers, something like @click.capture.prevent/stop ?

Comment: @jeremycastelli I've tried several combinations but no luck so far. Using CSS with `pointer-events: none;` is a solution of a sort, but still trying to find a way to do it purely with vue events handling. If I do find a solution will surely post it here.

Comment: Do you absolutely want to use targets or a walkaround could do the job for you ? Cause in that case it's simple, just pass parameters to the onClick function . something like this for example : `@click='onClick('element1')'`

Comment: @jeremycastelli hey that is also an interesting idea, didn't think of that. I was looking for handling it somehow using Vue event modifiers, but if that's not possible, this is also an elegant solution. Maybe you can post it as answer?

Comment: Cool ! glad it helps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve same result (maybe better) without using event target but by passing arguments to the onClick handler.

What I usually do when rendering clickable list is that I pass the entire item

```
<div v-for="element in elements" :key="'element' + item.id" class="'element' + element.id" @click="onClick(element)">
    <img :src='element.image_url' />
    <p>{{element.desc_text}}</p>
</div>
```

It then become easy to handle the onclick as you already have the element you want at your disposal

```
onClick(element) {
    console.log(element);
}
```